# Adding a background options for a WordPress theme

Tags: php, wordpress, themes

I am new to WordPress and just started designing a theme. I want to know what to do to add an option to change the background in my theme options in WordPress, so that the user can change it by themselves.

Comment: Well, you could add a custom setting for this in the [Customizer](https://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Customization_API). Have you looked into it yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add background support in themes for the background Customizations. open your functions.php file and add the following code inside it.

```
add_theme_support( 'custom-background' );
```